# Grub2 OS selection window freezing if the logitech wireless receiver is plugged in

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, logitech

In the screen where I get 10 seconds to select an OS before it starting the default one I get freeze errors when the wireless receiver is plugged in. The only way to fix it is to turn the computer off, remove the wireless receiver, select the OS and then put the receiver back in. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Solved by enabling legacy boot support